# Здравствуйте, не могу сделать инлайн кнопку, которая бы возвращала к сообщению с кнопками, которое уже есть ( то бишь "назад")

Tags: python, telebot, клавиатура

````
def pet(msg: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data="inv")
    markup.add(item)
    bot.send_message(chat_id=msg.chat.id, reply_markup=markup, text="текст") 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "inv")
def bt_inv(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton("назад", callback_data="inv_iza")
    markup.add(item)
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text=' Инвентарь', reply_markup=markup)```
````